# How to apply pandas.map() where the function takes more than 1 argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apply

Suppose I have a dataframe containing a column of probability. Now I create a map function which returns 1 if the probability is greater than a threshold value, otherwise returns 0. Now the catch is that I want to specify the threshold by giving it as an argument to the function, and then mapping it on the pandas dataframe.

Take the code example below:

```py
def partition(x,threshold):
    if x<threshold:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

df = pd.DataFrame({'probability':[0.2,0.8,0.4,0.95]})
df2 = df.map(partition)
```

My question is, how would the last line work, i.e. how do I pass the threshold value inside my map function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use [`Dataframe.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)

```
df2 = df.applymap(lambda x: partition(x, threshold=0.5))
```

Or if only one column:

```
df['probability']=df['probability'].apply(lambda x: partition(x, threshold=0.5))
```

but it is not neccesary here. You can do:

```
df2 = df.ge(threshold).astype(int)
```

I recommend you see [`it`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lambda` for that purpose:

```py
def partition(x,threshold):
    if x<threshold:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

df=pd.DataFrame({'probability':[0.2,0.8,0.4,0.95]})
df['probability']=df['probability'].map(lambda x: partition(x, threshold=0.5))
```

Comment: he has a Dataframe

Comment: True, and from the example it does seem like taking the whole data frame is not the way to go @ansev

Answer (score 1):

If there are extra arguments, it's better to use `apply()`:

```py
df['new'] = df['probability'].apply(partition, threshold=0.5)
```

or wrap the function with `functools.partial` and map this new function:

```py
from functools import partial
df['new'] = df['probability'].map(partial(partition, threshold=0.5))

# a bit more legibly
partition_05 = partial(partition, threshold=0.5)
df['new'] = df['probability'].map(partition_05)
```

You can pass the extra argument as a kwarg to `applymap()` too:

```py
df = df.applymap(partition, threshold=0.5)
```

---

That said, please use vectorized code wherever possible. For example, in the OP,

```py
df['new'] = (df['probability'] > 0.5) * 1
```

produces the desired column.